# Display Modal on DOM Element Update with MutationObserver

Tags: javascript, mutation-observers

I want to display a modal popup only after one of any DOM elements with the same class are updated. I am guessing MutationObserver is the best tool for this? Here is what I've got so far but it is not working...

```
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById("save-search-modal");
    
// select the target nodes for mutation observing
var target = document.getElementsByClassName("sidx-pill-value")[0];
    
// When .sidx-pill-value is updated, open the modal
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
        modal.style.display = "block";
    });
});

// configuration of the observer:
var config = { subtree: true, characterData: true, attributes: true, childList: true }

// pass in the target node, as well as the observer options
observer.observe(target, config);
```

Comment: MutationObservers are only for when you don't control the code that changes the elements. Do you control the code that changes the elements?

Comment: I do not. The elements are changed through user input in a third party plugin

Comment: Every thing looks ok to me, https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-ectn5u?file=index.js, maybe the problem is in other part of your code.